# Spring Boot builds fine but throws javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: remaining name: env/jmx/runtime when running

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot

I have an existing application that is building fine via gradle but when I run it through the embedded tomcat server, I get the following Exception.  Any idea on how to resolve?

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'mbeanExporter' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jmx/JmxAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter]:
>   Factory method 'mbeanExporter' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'mbeanServer' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jmx/JmxAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [javax.management.MBeanServer]: Factory method
>   'mbeanServer' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jmx.MBeanServerNotFoundException: Failed to
>   retrieve WebLogic MBeanServer from JNDI; nested exception is
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: remaining name: env/jmx/runtime
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:967)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:956)
>     at com.avada.main.Application.main(Application.java:15)

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem and had it fixed by excluding the `JmxAutoConfiguration` class from the Spring Boot config.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = JmxAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Application {...}
```

It seemed like Spring was trying to create a bean (`mbeanExporter`) detected in the weblogic api library, and this bean needed the `env/jmx/runtime` JNDI.

Answer (score 5):

You can skip loaded configuration of Spring Boot by adding the following line:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { JmxAutoConfiguration.class, EndpointMBeanExportAutoConfiguration.class})
```

The container in new version of Spring Boot (current: 1.5.4) try to load other beans inside application server jar so you need to add the exclusion (like: EndpointMBeanExportAutoConfiguration) of this setup.

Answer (score 2):

The MBean exporter think it's running on Weblogic:

> Failed to retrieve WebLogic MBeanServer from JNDI

That can only happen if `weblogic.management.Helper` on the classpath. You need to remove that class from the classpath. If you're not sure where that class could be, running Tomcat with `-verbose:class` will tell you.

Comment: Thanks Andy - I've found that class in a particular jar I'm including - `compile files('WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/wls-api.jar')` - any ideas on how to exclude weblogic.management.Helper from being compiled as apart of that jar?

Comment: Given that you're using Tomcat, can't you just remove the entire jar?

Comment: We interface with WebLogic so we need this jar

Answer (score 2):

For me what worked was to place the exclude on:

@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = JmxAutoConfiguration.class)